# bokeh version is abnormal (python 2.76, bokeh 4.2)

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I'm user of Bokeh

I update the Bokeh yesterday, but I found the abnormal version number

> > > import bokeh
> > >
> > > bokeh.**version** # under bar ???

result ---> '96d477c368eb4384b048cef164b41c572de1f43f'

????

I don't know that version number is abnormal number

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the git hash.  Try looking at `bokeh.__version__`.  We'll fix this up by the next release.

Thanks!